# Plot vertical lines from datapoints to zero axis in python

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot

I want to plot vertical lines from each point of my dataset to the zero axis. At the moment plot looks like this:

```
values = [0.0, 0.2, 0.0,  0.4, 1.4, 0.5]
times = [1, 4, 10, 12, 14, 20]
plt.plot(values,times,'o')
plt.show()
```

How to plot the vertical lines? I found in the documentation **axvline**, which however does vertical lines through the whole graph and I do not want it:

```
xcoords = [0.22058956, 0.33088437, 2.20589566]
for xc in xcoords:
    plt.axvline(x=xc)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can plot an arbitrary line from `c1 = [x1, y1]` to `c2 = [x2, y2]` using `plt.plot(c1, c2)`. So to plot these lines you can just do

```
xcoords = [0.22058956, 0.33088437, 2.20589566]
for xc in xcoords:
    plt.plot([xc, 0], [xc, Y-VALUE])
```

Answer (score 7):

## Use a `stem` plot

The least cumbersome solution employs [`matplotlib.pyplot.stem`](https://matplotlib.org/api/pyplot_api.html?highlight=matplotlib%20pyplot%20stem#matplotlib.pyplot.stem)

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
values = [0.0, 0.2, 0.0, 0.4, 1.4, 0.5]
times = [1, 4, 10, 12, 14, 20]
plt.stem(times,values)
plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: Also, if you want vertical lines only (no markers etc.), use `plt.stem(times,values, basefmt=' ', markerfmt=' ')`

Answer (score 2):

`axvline` has a paramater `ymax` that adjusts percent of the yrange, until which vline should last. In case when y axis is **tight**, the solution could be like this:

```
for i in range(len(times)):
    plt.axvline(values[i], ymax=float(times[i]) / max(times), color='b')
```